# JavaScript QP solver doens't give correct solution.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints, quadratic-programming

I'm solving a constrained optimization problem, where I have to find the vector $\mathbf{x}$ of dimensionality `N x 1`. The input vectors are $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ with dimensionality `N x 1`. The error function which I have to minimize is:

$$E(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^N(a_i-x_i)^2=(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{x})^T(\mathbf{a}-\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} - 2\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{a}$$

The term $\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{a}$ can be ignored, as it is just a constant term, and doesn't influence the choice of $\mathbf{x}$, so $E(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x} - 2\mathbf{a}^T\mathbf{x}$.

I've to minimize this error function subject to $N$ constraints:

$$x_i \ge \varepsilon_i \; \; \; \; \; \; \forall i \in [1, N] $$

where $\varepsilon_i$ is defined as:

$$\varepsilon_i =\begin{cases} k &for \; i = 1\\ x_{i-1} + h_{i - 1} + \eta &for \; i \gt 1 \end{cases}$$

for some constants $k$ and $\eta$.

So, its a quadratic programming problem. I've to use a QP solver to solve this problem in JavaScript, so I've found [numeric.js](http://www.numericjs.com/) which provides a function `solveQP` (The Quadratic Programming function numeric.solveQP() is based on [Alberto Santini's quadprog](https://github.com/albertosantini/node-quadprog), which is itself a port of the R package [quadprog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/).)

As R package [quadprog](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quadprog/) solves a QP problem of the form: $min(\frac{1}{2} x^T D x - d^T x)$ s.t. inequality constraints  $A^Tx \geq b_0$

So, to convert my problem into this problem, I get, $D = I$ (or $D = 2I$) and $d = 2\mathbf{a}$.
And my constraints are like:

$$x_1 \ge k$$
$$x_2 \ge x_1 + h_1 + \eta => x_2 - x_1 \ge h_1 + \eta$$
$$x_3 - x_2 \ge h_2 + \eta$$
$$\vdots$$

And so on. So I get: $A = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \ldots \\-1 & 1 & 0 \ldots\\0 & -1 & 1 \ldots\\\vdots \end{pmatrix} $, and $b_0 = \begin{pmatrix}k\\h_1+\eta\\h_2+\eta\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$

But when I code this, and call the `solveQP` method, the solution doesn't even satisfies the constraints.

E.g. for $N=3$, $\eta=2$, $k=5$, $h=\begin{pmatrix}2\\5\\5\end{pmatrix}$, and $a=\begin{pmatrix}8\\15\\16\end{pmatrix}$, it gives the solution as: $\begin{pmatrix}25.5\\28.25\\24.25\end{pmatrix}$, which doesn't satisfy the constraints because $x_2=28.25$ must be greater than or equal to $x_1+h_1+\eta = 25.5+2+2=29.5$ and $x_3=24.25$ must be greater than or equal to $x_2+h_2+\eta = 28.25+5+2=35.25$ (considering the current value of $x_2$). This solution is, if I use $D=I$. And if I use $D=2I$ (which I think, should not make any difference), the solution comes out to be: $\begin{pmatrix}13.999999999999996\\14.499999999999998\\10.499999999999998\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}14\\14.5\\10.5\end{pmatrix}$, which again, doesn't even satisfy the constraints.

So, does anyone know a better QP solver for JavaScript? Or am I making any mistake that I'm not able to figure out?

These are the functions from `numeric.js` that my solution needs:

```
// functions from numeric.js that my solution needs
function base0to1(A) {
    if(typeof A !== "object") { return A; }
    var ret = [], i,n=A.length;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) ret[i+1] = base0to1(A[i]);
    return ret;
}
function base1to0(A) {
    if(typeof A !== "object") { return A; }
    var ret = [], i,n=A.length;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++) ret[i-1] = base1to0(A[i]);
    return ret;
}

function dpofa(a, lda, n, info) {
    var i, j, jm1, k, t, s;

    for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
        info[1] = j;
        s = 0;
        jm1 = j - 1;
        if (jm1 < 1) {
            s = a[j][j] - s;
            if (s <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            a[j][j] = Math.sqrt(s);
        } else {
            for (k = 1; k <= jm1; k = k + 1) {
                //~ t = a[k][j] - ddot(k - 1, a[1][k], 1, a[1][j], 1);
                t = a[k][j];
                for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
                    t = t - (a[i][j] * a[i][k]);
                }
                t = t / a[k][k];
                a[k][j] = t;
                s = s + t * t;
            }
            s = a[j][j] - s;
            if (s <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            a[j][j] = Math.sqrt(s);
        }
        info[1] = 0;
    }
}

function dposl(a, lda, n, b) {
    var i, k, kb, t;

    for (k = 1; k <= n; k = k + 1) {
        //~ t = ddot(k - 1, a[1][k], 1, b[1], 1);
        t = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
            t = t + (a[i][k] * b[i]);
        }

        b[k] = (b[k] - t) / a[k][k];
    }

    for (kb = 1; kb <= n; kb = kb + 1) {
        k = n + 1 - kb;
        b[k] = b[k] / a[k][k];
        t = -b[k];
        //~ daxpy(k - 1, t, a[1][k], 1, b[1], 1);
        for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
            b[i] = b[i] + (t * a[i][k]);
        }
    }
}

function dpori(a, lda, n) {
    var i, j, k, kp1, t;

    for (k = 1; k <= n; k = k + 1) {
        a[k][k] = 1 / a[k][k];
        t = -a[k][k];
        //~ dscal(k - 1, t, a[1][k], 1);
        for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
            a[i][k] = t * a[i][k];
        }

        kp1 = k + 1;
        if (n < kp1) {
            break;
        }
        for (j = kp1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            t = a[k][j];
            a[k][j] = 0;
            //~ daxpy(k, t, a[1][k], 1, a[1][j], 1);
            for (i = 1; i <= k; i = i + 1) {
                a[i][j] = a[i][j] + (t * a[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }

}

function qpgen2(dmat, dvec, fddmat, n, sol, crval, amat,
    bvec, fdamat, q, meq, iact, nact, iter, work, ierr) {

    var i, j, l, l1, info, it1, iwzv, iwrv, iwrm, iwsv, iwuv, nvl, r, iwnbv,
        temp, sum, t1, tt, gc, gs, nu,
        t1inf, t2min,
        vsmall, tmpa, tmpb,
        go;

    r = Math.min(n, q);
    l = 2 * n + (r * (r + 5)) / 2 + 2 * q + 1;

    vsmall = 1.0e-60;
    do {
        vsmall = vsmall + vsmall;
        tmpa = 1 + 0.1 * vsmall;
        tmpb = 1 + 0.2 * vsmall;
    } while (tmpa <= 1 || tmpb <= 1);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        work[i] = dvec[i];
    }
    for (i = n + 1; i <= l; i = i + 1) {
        work[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
        iact[i] = 0;
    }

    info = [];

    if (ierr[1] === 0) {
        dpofa(dmat, fddmat, n, info);
        if (info[1] !== 0) {
            ierr[1] = 2;
            return;
        }
        dposl(dmat, fddmat, n, dvec);
        dpori(dmat, fddmat, n);
    } else {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            sol[j] = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= j; i = i + 1) {
                sol[j] = sol[j] + dmat[i][j] * dvec[i];
            }
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            dvec[j] = 0;
            for (i = j; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                dvec[j] = dvec[j] + dmat[j][i] * sol[i];
            }
        }
    }

    crval[1] = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
        sol[j] = dvec[j];
        crval[1] = crval[1] + work[j] * sol[j];
        work[j] = 0;
        for (i = j + 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
            dmat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    crval[1] = -crval[1] / 2;
    ierr[1] = 0;

    iwzv = n;
    iwrv = iwzv + n;
    iwuv = iwrv + r;
    iwrm = iwuv + r + 1;
    iwsv = iwrm + (r * (r + 1)) / 2;
    iwnbv = iwsv + q;

    for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            sum = sum + amat[j][i] * amat[j][i];
        }
        work[iwnbv + i] = Math.sqrt(sum);
    }
    nact = 0;
    iter[1] = 0;
    iter[2] = 0;

    function fn_goto_50() {
        iter[1] = iter[1] + 1;

        l = iwsv;
        for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
            l = l + 1;
            sum = -bvec[i];
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                sum = sum + amat[j][i] * sol[j];
            }
            if (Math.abs(sum) < vsmall) {
                sum = 0;
            }
            if (i > meq) {
                work[l] = sum;
            } else {
                work[l] = -Math.abs(sum);
                if (sum > 0) {
                    for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                        amat[j][i] = -amat[j][i];
                    }
                    bvec[i] = -bvec[i];
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
            work[iwsv + iact[i]] = 0;
        }

        nvl = 0;
        temp = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
            if (work[iwsv + i] < temp * work[iwnbv + i]) {
                nvl = i;
                temp = work[iwsv + i] / work[iwnbv + i];
            }
        }
        if (nvl === 0) {
            return 999;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_55() {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
            sum = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                sum = sum + dmat[j][i] * amat[j][nvl];
            }
            work[i] = sum;
        }

        l1 = iwzv;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
            work[l1 + i] = 0;
        }
        for (j = nact + 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                work[l1 + i] = work[l1 + i] + dmat[i][j] * work[j];
            }
        }

        t1inf = true;
        for (i = nact; i >= 1; i = i - 1) {
            sum = work[i];
            l = iwrm + (i * (i + 3)) / 2;
            l1 = l - i;
            for (j = i + 1; j <= nact; j = j + 1) {
                sum = sum - work[l] * work[iwrv + j];
                l = l + j;
            }
            sum = sum / work[l1];
            work[iwrv + i] = sum;
            if (iact[i] < meq) {
                // continue;
                break;
            }
            if (sum < 0) {
                // continue;
                break;
            }
            t1inf = false;
            it1 = i;
        }

        if (!t1inf) {
            t1 = work[iwuv + it1] / work[iwrv + it1];
            for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                if (iact[i] < meq) {
                    // continue;
                    break;
                }
                if (work[iwrv + i] < 0) {
                    // continue;
                    break;
                }
                temp = work[iwuv + i] / work[iwrv + i];
                if (temp < t1) {
                    t1 = temp;
                    it1 = i;
                }
            }
        }

        sum = 0;
        for (i = iwzv + 1; i <= iwzv + n; i = i + 1) {
            sum = sum + work[i] * work[i];
        }
        if (Math.abs(sum) <= vsmall) {
            if (t1inf) {
                ierr[1] = 1;
                // GOTO 999
                return 999;
            } else {
                for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                    work[iwuv + i] = work[iwuv + i] - t1 * work[iwrv + i];
                }
                work[iwuv + nact + 1] = work[iwuv + nact + 1] + t1;
                // GOTO 700
                return 700;
            }
        } else {
            sum = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                sum = sum + work[iwzv + i] * amat[i][nvl];
            }
            tt = -work[iwsv + nvl] / sum;
            t2min = true;
            if (!t1inf) {
                if (t1 < tt) {
                    tt = t1;
                    t2min = false;
                }
            }

            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                sol[i] = sol[i] + tt * work[iwzv + i];
                if (Math.abs(sol[i]) < vsmall) {
                    sol[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            crval[1] = crval[1] + tt * sum * (tt / 2 + work[iwuv + nact + 1]);
            for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                work[iwuv + i] = work[iwuv + i] - tt * work[iwrv + i];
            }
            work[iwuv + nact + 1] = work[iwuv + nact + 1] + tt;

            if (t2min) {
                nact = nact + 1;
                iact[nact] = nvl;

                l = iwrm + ((nact - 1) * nact) / 2 + 1;
                for (i = 1; i <= nact - 1; i = i + 1) {
                    work[l] = work[i];
                    l = l + 1;
                }

                if (nact === n) {
                    work[l] = work[n];
                } else {
                    for (i = n; i >= nact + 1; i = i - 1) {
                        if (work[i] === 0) {
                            // continue;
                            break;
                        }
                        gc = Math.max(Math.abs(work[i - 1]), Math.abs(work[i]));
                        gs = Math.min(Math.abs(work[i - 1]), Math.abs(work[i]));
                        if (work[i - 1] >= 0) {
                            temp = Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs / (gc * gc)));
                        } else {
                            temp = -Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs / (gc * gc)));
                        }
                        gc = work[i - 1] / temp;
                        gs = work[i] / temp;

                        if (gc === 1) {
                            // continue;
                            break;
                        }
                        if (gc === 0) {
                            work[i - 1] = gs * temp;
                            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                                temp = dmat[j][i - 1];
                                dmat[j][i - 1] = dmat[j][i];
                                dmat[j][i] = temp;
                            }
                        } else {
                            work[i - 1] = temp;
                            nu = gs / (1 + gc);
                            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                                temp = gc * dmat[j][i - 1] + gs * dmat[j][i];
                                dmat[j][i] = nu * (dmat[j][i - 1] + temp) - dmat[j][i];
                                dmat[j][i - 1] = temp;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    work[l] = work[nact];
                }
            } else {
                sum = -bvec[nvl];
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                    sum = sum + sol[j] * amat[j][nvl];
                }
                if (nvl > meq) {
                    work[iwsv + nvl] = sum;
                } else {
                    work[iwsv + nvl] = -Math.abs(sum);
                    if (sum > 0) {
                        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                            amat[j][nvl] = -amat[j][nvl];
                        }
                        bvec[nvl] = -bvec[nvl];
                    }
                }
                // GOTO 700
                return 700;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_797() {
        l = iwrm + (it1 * (it1 + 1)) / 2 + 1;
        l1 = l + it1;
        if (work[l1] === 0) {
            // GOTO 798
            return 798;
        }
        gc = Math.max(Math.abs(work[l1 - 1]), Math.abs(work[l1]));
        gs = Math.min(Math.abs(work[l1 - 1]), Math.abs(work[l1]));
        if (work[l1 - 1] >= 0) {
            temp = Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs / (gc * gc)));
        } else {
            temp = -Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs / (gc * gc)));
        }
        gc = work[l1 - 1] / temp;
        gs = work[l1] / temp;

        if (gc === 1) {
            // GOTO 798
            return 798;
        }
        if (gc === 0) {
            for (i = it1 + 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                temp = work[l1 - 1];
                work[l1 - 1] = work[l1];
                work[l1] = temp;
                l1 = l1 + i;
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                temp = dmat[i][it1];
                dmat[i][it1] = dmat[i][it1 + 1];
                dmat[i][it1 + 1] = temp;
            }
        } else {
            nu = gs / (1 + gc);
            for (i = it1 + 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                temp = gc * work[l1 - 1] + gs * work[l1];
                work[l1] = nu * (work[l1 - 1] + temp) - work[l1];
                work[l1 - 1] = temp;
                l1 = l1 + i;
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                temp = gc * dmat[i][it1] + gs * dmat[i][it1 + 1];
                dmat[i][it1 + 1] = nu * (dmat[i][it1] + temp) - dmat[i][it1 + 1];
                dmat[i][it1] = temp;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_798() {
        l1 = l - it1;
        for (i = 1; i <= it1; i = i + 1) {
            work[l1] = work[l];
            l = l + 1;
            l1 = l1 + 1;
        }

        work[iwuv + it1] = work[iwuv + it1 + 1];
        iact[it1] = iact[it1 + 1];
        it1 = it1 + 1;
        if (it1 < nact) {
            // GOTO 797
            return 797;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_799() {
        work[iwuv + nact] = work[iwuv + nact + 1];
        work[iwuv + nact + 1] = 0;
        iact[nact] = 0;
        nact = nact - 1;
        iter[2] = iter[2] + 1;

        return 0;
    }

    go = 0;
    while (true) {
        go = fn_goto_50();
        if (go === 999) {
            return;
        }
        while (true) {
            go = fn_goto_55();
            if (go === 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (go === 999) {
                return;
            }
            if (go === 700) {
                if (it1 === nact) {
                    fn_goto_799();
                } else {
                    while (true) {
                        fn_goto_797();
                        go = fn_goto_798();
                        if (go !== 797) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    fn_goto_799();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

function solveQP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq, factorized) {
    Dmat = base0to1(Dmat);
    dvec = base0to1(dvec);
    Amat = base0to1(Amat);
    var i, n, q,
        nact, r,
        crval = [], iact = [], sol = [], work = [], iter = [],
        message;

    meq = meq || 0;
    factorized = factorized ? base0to1(factorized) : [undefined, 0];
    bvec = bvec ? base0to1(bvec) : [];

    // In Fortran the array index starts from 1
    n = Dmat.length - 1;
    q = Amat[1].length - 1;

    if (!bvec) {
        for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
            bvec[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
        iact[i] = 0;
    }
    nact = 0;
    r = Math.min(n, q);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        sol[i] = 0;
    }
    crval[1] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= (2 * n + (r * (r + 5)) / 2 + 2 * q + 1); i = i + 1) {
        work[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i = i + 1) {
        iter[i] = 0;
    }

    qpgen2(Dmat, dvec, n, n, sol, crval, Amat,
        bvec, n, q, meq, iact, nact, iter, work, factorized);

    message = "";
    if (factorized[1] === 1) {
        message = "constraints are inconsistent, no solution!";
    }
    if (factorized[1] === 2) {
        message = "matrix D in quadratic function is not positive definite!";
    }

    return {
        solution: base1to0(sol),
        value: base1to0(crval),
        unconstrained_solution: base1to0(dvec),
        iterations: base1to0(iter),
        iact: base1to0(iact),
        message: message
    };
}
```

My code that constructs $D$, $d$, $A$, and $b_0$, and calls the `solveQP` function:

```
// main
// solve QP with 1/2 (x^T) D (x) - (d^T)(x) s.t. (A^T)x >= b

var h = [2, 5, 5]; // vector of heights
var a = [8, 15, 16]; // input vector
var N = h.length;
var eta = 2;
var k = 5;

// print h
document.write("h...\n");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    document.write(h[i] + ", ");
}


// print a
document.write("\na...\n");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    document.write(a[i] + ", ");
}

// print N
document.write("\nN..." + N + "\n");

// print eta
document.write("\neta..." + eta + "\n");

// print k
document.write("\nk..." + k + "\n");

// construct DMat = 2I, and dvec = 2a
var DMat = [];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    DMat[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if (i != j){
            DMat[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else{
            DMat[i][j] = 2;
        }
    }
}

// print DMat
document.write("\nDMat...\n");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        document.write(DMat[i][j] + ", ");
    }
    document.write("\n");
}

// now dvec
var dvec = [];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    dvec[i] = a[i] * 2;
}

// print dvec
document.write("\ndvec...\n");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    document.write(dvec[i] + ", ");
}

// construct AMat and bvec for constraints
var AMat = [];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    AMat[i] = [];
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        if (i == j){
            AMat[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else if ((j+1) == i){
            AMat[i][j] = -1;
        }
        else{
            AMat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

// print AMat
document.write("\nAMat...\n");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
        document.write(AMat[i][j] + ", ");
    }
    document.write("\n");
}

// now bvec
var bvec = [];
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    if (i == 0){
        bvec[i] = k;
    }
    else{
        bvec[i] = h[i - 1] + eta;
    }
}

// print bvec
document.write("\nbvec...\n");
for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
    document.write(bvec[i] + ", ");
}

// solve QP with 1/2 (xT) D (x) - (dT)(x) s.t. Ax >= b
var res = solveQP(DMat, dvec, AMat, bvec, 0, false);
document.write("\nSolution...\n");

for (i = 0; i < res.solution.length; i++){
    document.write(res.solution[i] + ", ");
}
```

Comment: Whether you use $D$ or $2D$ makes a big difference of course, as you have both a quadratic and a linear term. If you double the quadratic term but don't double the linear term, you have changed the objective. FYI, the optimal solution is $(8,12,19)$.

Comment: Oh, that means I have to use $2D$ then to cancel out the $1/2$, but I've used it too, still this solver doesn't give me the solution.

Comment: Your problem lies in the implementation of the constraints as you generate infeasible solutions. That is not in any sense related to the objective. However, it is more of a programming issue than mathematical issue at this point.

Comment: I've implemented the same using the actual R package, and it gives perfectly correct output. So I think, it's the issue of this "numeric.js". Do you know any good QP solver for JavaScript?

Comment: I only use MATLAB

Comment: Ahan, that's the problem, I've to implement it for the client side of a web application, that leaves me with no choice other than JS.

Comment: As always, start with something (more) trivial, and build from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was some error in `numeric.js`, so I copied the code from [Alberto Santini's quadprog](https://github.com/albertosantini/node-quadprog) on which `numeric.js`'s `solveQP` was based on. Below, it is given:

```
var vsmall = (function () {
    var epsilon = 1.0e-60,
        tmpa,
        tmpb;

    do {
        epsilon = epsilon + epsilon;
        tmpa = 1 + 0.1 * epsilon;
        tmpb = 1 + 0.2 * epsilon;
    } while (tmpa <= 1 || tmpb <= 1);

    return epsilon;
}());

function dpori(a, lda, n) {
    var i, j, k, kp1, t;

    for (k = 1; k <= n; k = k + 1) {
        a[k][k] = 1 / a[k][k];
        t = -a[k][k];
        // dscal(k - 1, t, a[1][k], 1);
        for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
            a[i][k] = t * a[i][k];
        }

        kp1 = k + 1;
        if (n < kp1) {
            break;
        }
        for (j = kp1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            t = a[k][j];
            a[k][j] = 0;
            // daxpy(k, t, a[1][k], 1, a[1][j], 1);
            for (i = 1; i <= k; i = i + 1) {
                a[i][j] = a[i][j] + (t * a[i][k]);
            }
        }
    }

}

function dposl(a, lda, n, b) {
    var i, k, kb, t;

    for (k = 1; k <= n; k = k + 1) {
        // t = ddot(k - 1, a[1][k], 1, b[1], 1);
        t = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
            t = t + (a[i][k] * b[i]);
        }

        b[k] = (b[k] - t) / a[k][k];
    }

    for (kb = 1; kb <= n; kb = kb + 1) {
        k = n + 1 - kb;
        b[k] = b[k] / a[k][k];
        t = -b[k];
        // daxpy(k - 1, t, a[1][k], 1, b[1], 1);
        for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
            b[i] = b[i] + (t * a[i][k]);
        }
    }
}

function dpofa(a, lda, n, info) {
    var i, j, jm1, k, t, s;

    for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
        info[1] = j;
        s = 0;
        jm1 = j - 1;
        if (jm1 < 1) {
            s = a[j][j] - s;
            if (s <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            a[j][j] = Math.sqrt(s);
        } else {
            for (k = 1; k <= jm1; k = k + 1) {
                // t = a[k][j] - ddot(k - 1, a[1][k], 1, a[1][j], 1);
                t = a[k][j];
                for (i = 1; i < k; i = i + 1) {
                    t = t - (a[i][j] * a[i][k]);
                }
                t = t / a[k][k];
                a[k][j] = t;
                s = s + t * t;
            }
            s = a[j][j] - s;
            if (s <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            a[j][j] = Math.sqrt(s);
        }
        info[1] = 0;
    }
}

/*eslint-disable max-len */
function qpgen2(dmat, dvec, fddmat, n, sol, lagr, crval, amat, bvec, fdamat, q, meq, iact, nact, iter, work, ierr) {
/*eslint-enable */
    var i, j, l, l1, info, it1, iwzv, iwrv, iwrm, iwsv, iwuv, nvl, r, iwnbv,
        temp, sum, t1, tt, gc, gs, nu,
        t1inf, t2min,
        go;

    r = Math.min(n, q);
    l = 2 * n + (r * (r + 5)) / 2 + 2 * q + 1;

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        work[i] = dvec[i];
    }
    for (i = n + 1; i <= l; i = i + 1) {
        work[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
        iact[i] = 0;
        lagr[i] = 0;
    }

    info = [];

    if (ierr[1] === 0) {
        dpofa(dmat, fddmat, n, info);
        if (info[1] !== 0) {
            ierr[1] = 2;
            return;
        }
        dposl(dmat, fddmat, n, dvec);
        dpori(dmat, fddmat, n);
    } else {
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            sol[j] = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= j; i = i + 1) {
                sol[j] = sol[j] + dmat[i][j] * dvec[i];
            }
        }
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            dvec[j] = 0;
            for (i = j; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                dvec[j] = dvec[j] + dmat[j][i] * sol[i];
            }
        }
    }

    crval[1] = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
        sol[j] = dvec[j];
        crval[1] = crval[1] + work[j] * sol[j];
        work[j] = 0;
        for (i = j + 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
            dmat[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
    crval[1] = -crval[1] / 2;
    ierr[1] = 0;

    iwzv = n;
    iwrv = iwzv + n;
    iwuv = iwrv + r;
    iwrm = iwuv + r + 1;
    iwsv = iwrm + (r * (r + 1)) / 2;
    iwnbv = iwsv + q;

    for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            sum = sum + amat[j][i] * amat[j][i];
        }
        work[iwnbv + i] = Math.sqrt(sum);
    }
    nact = 0;
    iter[1] = 0;
    iter[2] = 0;

    function fn_goto_50() {
        iter[1] = iter[1] + 1;

        l = iwsv;
        for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
            l = l + 1;
            sum = -bvec[i];
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                sum = sum + amat[j][i] * sol[j];
            }
            if (Math.abs(sum) < vsmall) {
                sum = 0;
            }
            if (i > meq) {
                work[l] = sum;
            } else {
                work[l] = -Math.abs(sum);
                if (sum > 0) {
                    for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                        amat[j][i] = -amat[j][i];
                    }
                    bvec[i] = -bvec[i];
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
            work[iwsv + iact[i]] = 0;
        }

        nvl = 0;
        temp = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
            if (work[iwsv + i] < temp * work[iwnbv + i]) {
                nvl = i;
                temp = work[iwsv + i] / work[iwnbv + i];
            }
        }
        if (nvl === 0) {
            for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                lagr[iact[i]] = work[iwuv + i];
            }
            return 999;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_55() {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
            sum = 0;
            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                sum = sum + dmat[j][i] * amat[j][nvl];
            }
            work[i] = sum;
        }

        l1 = iwzv;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
            work[l1 + i] = 0;
        }
        for (j = nact + 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                work[l1 + i] = work[l1 + i] + dmat[i][j] * work[j];
            }
        }

        t1inf = true;
        for (i = nact; i >= 1; i = i - 1) {
            sum = work[i];
            l = iwrm + (i * (i + 3)) / 2;
            l1 = l - i;
            for (j = i + 1; j <= nact; j = j + 1) {
                sum = sum - work[l] * work[iwrv + j];
                l = l + j;
            }
            sum = sum / work[l1];
            work[iwrv + i] = sum;
            if (iact[i] <= meq) {
                continue;
            }
            if (sum <= 0) {
                continue;
            }
            t1inf = false;
            it1 = i;
        }

        if (!t1inf) {
            t1 = work[iwuv + it1] / work[iwrv + it1];
            for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                if (iact[i] <= meq) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (work[iwrv + i] <= 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                temp = work[iwuv + i] / work[iwrv + i];
                if (temp < t1) {
                    t1 = temp;
                    it1 = i;
                }
            }
        }

        sum = 0;
        for (i = iwzv + 1; i <= iwzv + n; i = i + 1) {
            sum = sum + work[i] * work[i];
        }
        if (Math.abs(sum) <= vsmall) {
            if (t1inf) {
                ierr[1] = 1;
                // GOTO 999
                return 999;
            } else {
                for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                    work[iwuv + i] = work[iwuv + i] - t1 * work[iwrv + i];
                }
                work[iwuv + nact + 1] = work[iwuv + nact + 1] + t1;
                // GOTO 700
                return 700;
            }
        } else {
            sum = 0;
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                sum = sum + work[iwzv + i] * amat[i][nvl];
            }
            tt = -work[iwsv + nvl] / sum;
            t2min = true;
            if (!t1inf) {
                if (t1 < tt) {
                    tt = t1;
                    t2min = false;
                }
            }

            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                sol[i] = sol[i] + tt * work[iwzv + i];
                if (Math.abs(sol[i]) < vsmall) {
                    sol[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            crval[1] = crval[1] + tt * sum * (tt / 2 + work[iwuv + nact + 1]);
            for (i = 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                work[iwuv + i] = work[iwuv + i] - tt * work[iwrv + i];
            }
            work[iwuv + nact + 1] = work[iwuv + nact + 1] + tt;

            if (t2min) {
                nact = nact + 1;
                iact[nact] = nvl;

                l = iwrm + ((nact - 1) * nact) / 2 + 1;
                for (i = 1; i <= nact - 1; i = i + 1) {
                    work[l] = work[i];
                    l = l + 1;
                }

                if (nact === n) {
                    work[l] = work[n];
                } else {
                    for (i = n; i >= nact + 1; i = i - 1) {
                        if (work[i] === 0) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        gc = Math.max(Math.abs(work[i - 1]), Math.abs(work[i]));
                        gs = Math.min(Math.abs(work[i - 1]), Math.abs(work[i]));
                        if (work[i - 1] >= 0) {
                            temp = Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs /
                                (gc * gc)));
                        } else {
                            temp = -Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs /
                                (gc * gc)));
                        }
                        gc = work[i - 1] / temp;
                        gs = work[i] / temp;

                        if (gc === 1) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (gc === 0) {
                            work[i - 1] = gs * temp;
                            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                                temp = dmat[j][i - 1];
                                dmat[j][i - 1] = dmat[j][i];
                                dmat[j][i] = temp;
                            }
                        } else {
                            work[i - 1] = temp;
                            nu = gs / (1 + gc);
                            for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                                temp = gc * dmat[j][i - 1] + gs * dmat[j][i];
                                dmat[j][i] = nu * (dmat[j][i - 1] + temp) -
                                    dmat[j][i];
                                dmat[j][i - 1] = temp;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    work[l] = work[nact];
                }
            } else {
                sum = -bvec[nvl];
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                    sum = sum + sol[j] * amat[j][nvl];
                }
                if (nvl > meq) {
                    work[iwsv + nvl] = sum;
                } else {
                    work[iwsv + nvl] = -Math.abs(sum);
                    if (sum > 0) {
                        for (j = 1; j <= n; j = j + 1) {
                            amat[j][nvl] = -amat[j][nvl];
                        }
                        bvec[nvl] = -bvec[nvl];
                    }
                }
                // GOTO 700
                return 700;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_797() {
        l = iwrm + (it1 * (it1 + 1)) / 2 + 1;
        l1 = l + it1;
        if (work[l1] === 0) {
            // GOTO 798
            return 798;
        }
        gc = Math.max(Math.abs(work[l1 - 1]), Math.abs(work[l1]));
        gs = Math.min(Math.abs(work[l1 - 1]), Math.abs(work[l1]));
        if (work[l1 - 1] >= 0) {
            temp = Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs / (gc * gc)));
        } else {
            temp = -Math.abs(gc * Math.sqrt(1 + gs * gs / (gc * gc)));
        }
        gc = work[l1 - 1] / temp;
        gs = work[l1] / temp;

        if (gc === 1) {
            // GOTO 798
            return 798;
        }
        if (gc === 0) {
            for (i = it1 + 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                temp = work[l1 - 1];
                work[l1 - 1] = work[l1];
                work[l1] = temp;
                l1 = l1 + i;
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                temp = dmat[i][it1];
                dmat[i][it1] = dmat[i][it1 + 1];
                dmat[i][it1 + 1] = temp;
            }
        } else {
            nu = gs / (1 + gc);
            for (i = it1 + 1; i <= nact; i = i + 1) {
                temp = gc * work[l1 - 1] + gs * work[l1];
                work[l1] = nu * (work[l1 - 1] + temp) - work[l1];
                work[l1 - 1] = temp;
                l1 = l1 + i;
            }
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
                temp = gc * dmat[i][it1] + gs * dmat[i][it1 + 1];
                dmat[i][it1 + 1] = nu * (dmat[i][it1] + temp) -
                    dmat[i][it1 + 1];
                dmat[i][it1] = temp;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_798() {
        l1 = l - it1;
        for (i = 1; i <= it1; i = i + 1) {
            work[l1] = work[l];
            l = l + 1;
            l1 = l1 + 1;
        }

        work[iwuv + it1] = work[iwuv + it1 + 1];
        iact[it1] = iact[it1 + 1];
        it1 = it1 + 1;
        if (it1 < nact) {
            // GOTO 797
            return 797;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    function fn_goto_799() {
        work[iwuv + nact] = work[iwuv + nact + 1];
        work[iwuv + nact + 1] = 0;
        iact[nact] = 0;
        nact = nact - 1;
        iter[2] = iter[2] + 1;

        return 0;
    }

    go = 0;
    while (true) {
        go = fn_goto_50();
        if (go === 999) {
            return;
        }
        while (true) {
            go = fn_goto_55();
            if (go === 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (go === 999) {
                return;
            }
            if (go === 700) {
                if (it1 === nact) {
                    fn_goto_799();
                } else {
                    while (true) {
                        fn_goto_797();
                        go = fn_goto_798();
                        if (go !== 797) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    fn_goto_799();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

function solveQP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec, meq, factorized) {
    var i, n, q,
        nact, r,
        crval = [], iact = [], sol = [], lagr = [], work = [], iter = [],
        message = "";

    meq = meq || 0;
    factorized = factorized || [undefined, 0];
    bvec = bvec || [];

    // In Fortran the array index starts from 1
    n = Dmat.length - 1;
    q = Amat[1].length - 1;

    if (!bvec) {
        for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
            bvec[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    if (n !== Dmat[1].length - 1) {
        message = "Dmat is not symmetric!";
    }
    if (n !== dvec.length - 1) {
        message = "Dmat and dvec are incompatible!";
    }
    if (n !== Amat.length - 1) {
        message = "Amat and dvec are incompatible!";
    }
    if (q !== bvec.length - 1) {
        message = "Amat and bvec are incompatible!";
    }
    if ((meq > q) || (meq < 0)) {
        message = "Value of meq is invalid!";
    }

    if (message !== "") {
        return {
            message: message
        };
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= q; i = i + 1) {
        iact[i] = 0;
        lagr[i] = 0;
    }
    nact = 0;
    r = Math.min(n, q);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        sol[i] = 0;
    }
    crval[1] = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= (2 * n + (r * (r + 5)) / 2 + 2 * q + 1); i = i + 1) {
        work[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i = i + 1) {
        iter[i] = 0;
    }

    qpgen2(Dmat, dvec, n, n, sol, lagr, crval, Amat,
        bvec, n, q, meq, iact, nact, iter, work, factorized);

    if (factorized[1] === 1) {
        message = "constraints are inconsistent, no solution!";
    }
    if (factorized[1] === 2) {
        message = "matrix D in quadratic function is not positive definite!";
    }

    return {
        solution: sol,
        Lagrangian: lagr,
        value: crval,
        unconstrained_solution: dvec,
        iterations: iter,
        iact: iact,
        message: message
    };
}
```

This code uses 1-based indexed arrays instead of standard JS 0-based indexed arrays (So you can leave out the index 0, and only store the values starting from 1).

And I was making one mistake too, which was: the parameter `AMat` in `solveQP` should be $A^T$, not $A$. So anyone else looking for JavaScript QP solver, this one is working for me, you can use it too.